# application to Mittag Leffler theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Show that there is a holomorphic function $f \in H\left(\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{Z}\right)$ such that for each integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, there is a holomorphic function  $f_n \in H\left(D\left(n,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$ such that for each $z \in D'\left(n,\frac{1}{2}\right) $ we have

$f(z) = f_n(z) + \exp\left(\frac{1}{z-n}\right) $

My work,
Since we have for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ the function $f_n(z)=\frac{1}{z-n} \in D'\left(n,\frac{1}{2}\right)$then by Mitteg -Leffler theorem there is a function $f \in H(\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{Z})$ such that for each $n$ the holomorphic function $f-f_n \in H\left(D'\left(n,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$ has removable singuarlity.

I am not sure how to get the function $\exp\left(\frac{1}{z-n}\right)$ in the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $n \ne 0$ the Taylor series at zero of $\exp\left(\frac{1}{z-n}\right)$ has radius of convergence $|n|$ and let $g_{n,m}$ its $m$th truncation for each $n \in \mathbb Z, n \ne 0$.

For each $n \ne 0$ pick $k_n, |g_{n,k_n}(z)-\exp\left(\frac{1}{z-n}\right)| \le \frac{1}{2^{|n|}}, |z| \le \frac{|n|}{2}$

Let $f(z)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)+\sum_{|n| \ne 0}(\exp\left(\frac{1}{z-n}\right)-g_{n,k_n}(z))$.

Note that for each compact set $K \subset \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{Z}$ there is an $N_K$ st $K \subset D_{0}(|n|/2), |n| \ge N_K$ showing that $\sum_{|n| \ge N_K}(\exp\left(\frac{1}{z-n}\right)-g_{n,k_n}(z))$ converges normally (absolutely and uniformly) on $K$ so $f$ is well defined and holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{Z}$

But clearly $f(z)-\exp\left(\frac{1}{z-n}\right)=f_n(z)$ is holomorphic at $n$ too for each $n \in \mathbb Z$ (so $f_n$ is holomorphic in $(\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{Z}) \cup n$) and in particular it is holomorphic on a disc of radius $1/2$ around $n$ since the singularities are separated by at least $1$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: happy to be of help